# call javascript function only once inside if statment

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this if statement  I can call a function to alert a message if the statement  are true but the problem I get the message more that one time every time I click on ok button on the message box I get the same message box, again and again, I want to get the message only one time (I want to call the function only one time in the if statement ) are there any way for that  ?

My if statement loop

```
if(brd_side == COLOURS.WHITE) {
     firstmassege();
} else {
     secondmassege();
}
```

My functions :

```
function firstmassege() {
    alert('the first massege');
}

function secondmassege() {
    alert('the second massege');
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the value of brd_side anywhere?

Comment: @webbm yes this value can changed inside the webpage

Comment: Until that value is not equal to `COLOURS.WHITE` it will always call `firstmassege();`

Comment: can you poste your whole code , it seems that the event is trigger multiple time ( inside ajax , or other events  !)

Comment: @webbm that's only changed one time on the game when the player lose or win but the if statement  check that alwayes that what i mean

Comment: @bRIMOs the code are +600 line i will try to paste more

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `flag` to store the status. Please see the code below.

```js
$('#btn').click(firstmessage)

var clicked = false;
function firstmessage() {
 console.log('other statements...')
     if(!clicked){
           alert('the first massege');
     }
      clicked = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

In your case it will be like below

```
var flag =false;
    if (!flag){

     firstmessage();
     flag = true;

    }
```

Comment: can i use the same way with ajax url calling?

Comment: i get this massage after i run your code 
"prevent this page from creating additional dialogs"

Comment: the above code is for getting an idea about the problm..no the exact soln

Answer (score 0):

This Code should simply work. Hope this would be useful. This displays the first message only once and the second message after the button is clicked for the second time as required.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to test the Function</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click </button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var executed = false;

function myFunction() {


if (!executed){

 firstmessage();
 executed = true;

} else {
  secondmessage();

}
}


function firstmessage() {
       alert('the first message');

}

     function secondmessage() {
            alert('the second message');

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `one` in jquery:

```
$('#myButton').one('click', function(){ alert('Hi!');});
```